# Bug in ArcGIS Spatial Adjustment with Geometric Networks?

Tags: arcgis-9.3, geometric-network, affine-transformation, spatial-adjustment

I am trying to do spatial adjustment between two datasets as shown in the the figure below. The Pipe line(selected(green color)) is part of a Geometric Network. It has three vertices.

[image: Before Spatial Adjust]

When I perform the spatial Adjustment(tried Similarity and Affine transformation..), the Two end vertices goes where they should go but the middle vertex stays where it was before. In some other cases i observed, the entire segment stayed in its initial place without making a movement.

[image: After Spatial Adjust]

Is this a normal scenario while spatial adjusting features with Geometric Networks in ArcGIS? I am using ArcGIS 9.3. The spatial adjustment preview window shows data in the coorrect location as it should be.

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you drop the geometric network?

Comment: @KirkKuykendall No..it works fine without geometric network..tested in 9.3 and 10.

Comment: Do you have ArcGIS Desktop SP5 installed? They resolved some issues related geometric networks. See here :- http://gisupdates.esri.com/10sp5/ArcGIS/ArcGIS10sp5-issues.htm

Comment: @Raj - This issue is not mentioned in that list..

Comment: So you see the same bug in 10.0?  Do you have any connectivity rules set up?  Is there (or was there) a junction feature at the vertex that fails to move?  (In other words is the feature being moved a complex edge feature, or a simple edge feature?)